# I've set up an extra field for all the available widgets. How do I show it's value in the front-end?

Tags: filters, widgets

Thanks to another great post here I managed to set up an extra field (called "subtitle") for all WP Widgets. Now I am trying to make all WP widgets display the value of this extra field (naturally, after_title, since it's the subtitle), but I can't quite figure this out.

Here is the code I use to create the extra field for all the widgets:

```
function gcc_in_widget_form($t,$return,$instance){
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'text' => '', 'float' => 'none') );

if ( !isset($instance['subtitle']) )
    $instance['subtitle'] = null;
?>
<!-- SUBTITLE -->
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $t->get_field_id( 'subtitle' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Subtitle:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $t->get_field_id( 'subtitle' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $t->get_field_name( 'subtitle' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $instance['subtitle'];; ?>" />
</p>
$return = null;
return array($t,$return,$instance);
}
function gcc_in_widget_form_update($instance, $new_instance, $old_instance){
  $instance['subtitle'] = strip_tags($new_instance['subtitle']);
  return $instance;
}

add_action('in_widget_form', 'gcc_in_widget_form',5,3);   
add_filter('widget_update_callback', 'gcc_in_widget_form_update',5,3);    
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'gcc_dynamic_sidebar_params');
```

And here is how I am trying to show the field's value in the front-end:

```
function gcc_dynamic_sidebar_params($params){
  global $wp_registered_widgets;
  $widget_id = $params[0]['widget_id'];
  $widget_obj = $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id];
  $widget_opt = get_option($widget_obj['callback'][0]->option_name);
  $widget_num = $widget_obj['params'][0]['number'];

  $params[0]['after_title'] .= 'how to display the value of the instance['subtitle']??';

  return $params;
}
```

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't a filter on `widget_title` do this?

```
function widget_title_wpse_206841($title,$instance) {
  // var_dump($instance);
  if (!empty($instance['subtitle'])) {
    $title .= ' something '.$instance['subtitle'].' something ';
  }
  return $title;
}
add_filter('widget_title','widget_title_wpse_206841',10,2);
```

Comment: Aaaah, you are so right!!! Why did I feel the need to make things more complicated? Thanks so much for this!